# Set N item from a List as a Variable

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and writing a small script to set an RGB color where two of the RGB colors are randint(0,255) and the third (selected randomly) is 0.

To acomplish this, I have this:

```
import time
from random import *
from neopixel import *

print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

while True:

    colorList = [0, randint(0,255), randint(0,255)]
    shuffle(colorList)
    rColor = ???
    gColor = ???
    bColor = ???
    time.sleep(1)
```

I 'm having a lot of luck finding the answer but if I wanted to extract the first item from the list and set it to rColor, the second for gColor and etc, what Python function could I use to do that?

Edit: My end goal format would be an output that was simply "0, 150, 150".  The NeoPixel library I am working with is picky so that is the literal format I am aiming for.

Comment: Remove the 3 specified lines and replace them with   `rColor, gColor, bColor = colorList`. this line should do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To set the color values to three variables. Use

   ```
   r, g, b = colorList
   ```

   or

   ```
   r = colorList[0]
   g = colorList[1]
   b = colorList[2]
   ```
2. If the meaning of 'output' is print the result to console. Then use

   ```
   print(*colorList, sep=', ')
   ```
3. If you need a string '0, 150, 150'

   ```
   result = ', '.join(map(str, colorList))
   ```

   or

   ```
   result = ', '.join([str(x) for x in colorList])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do the trick.

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint, shuffle

while True:
    color_list = [0, randint(0,255), randint(0,255)]
    shuffle(color_list)
    r_color, g_color, b_color = color_list
    # sets colors to a string like "12, 10, 0"
    colors = ', '.join(str(color) for color in color_list)
    # print (colors) 
    sleep(1)
```

EDIT: added lines to include your edit